# c++ multithreading synchronization with a changing amount of resources

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization, locking

I'm having some trouble finding a way to synchronize threads when the amount of resources is unknown/changing. The problem:

There is an array of resources R that is shared between a number of threads, and each thread can do one of 3 actions:

1. create and add a new resource to the array (thus increasing it's size).
2. delete a resource from the array (thus decreasing it's size).
3. access a resource (write/read it's value).

every action outputs a success/fail message to the user. every resource has a unique ID. The purpose is to allow as much parallelability as possible, so locking all of the resources(the whole array) for each thread action is not an option.

one problem with this is that each time a thread adds a new resource to the array it needs to create a lock for the resource as well, which creates a problem that after the lock is created by the creating thread, the lock can be grabbed by an accessing thread before the creating thread has time to initialize the created resource value.

another problem is a scenario when a thread tries to access a non-existing resource, so in that case it will check if the resource exists and output an error message to the user if its not, but before it outputs the error message another thread creates the resource(after the accessing thread checked if the resource exists) so the error message will be output after the success message(mixed order).

I'd like to hear ideas on how to handle this sort of problem.
thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you need a thread safe vector. Unless you only take from the from and add to the rear then you can use a lock free queue.

Comment: I wrote a lockfree, fixed-capacity vector, but with more restrictions than what you need (multiple threads can add elements, a single thread can traverse the elements and remove them while traversing). Still, if you're interested, it's here : https://github.com/OlivierSohn/cpp.algorithms/blob/master/include/staticvector.lockfree.scmp.hpp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, as you change the array from multiple threads, the array must be thread-safe, so keep a lock for the whole array and acquire it once doing any of that three operations.

> one problem with this is that each time a thread adds a new resource to the array it needs to create a lock for the resource as well, which creates a problem that after the lock is created by the creating thread, the lock can be grabbed by an accessing thread before the creating thread has time to initialize the created resource value.

for this issue, make sure each thread locks the array while adding and initializing a resource to it. if the procedure of initialization is a time consuming task, do the parts that can be done asynchronously before adding resource to array. for example if you want to add an object to array, that takes so much time to initialize, and can be initialized asynchronously, first create and initialize that object then lock the array while adding a pointer of the object to the array.

> another problem is a scenario when a thread tries to access a non-existing resource, so in that case it will check if the resource exists and output an error message to the user if its not, but before it outputs the error message another thread creates the resource(after the accessing thread checked if the resource exists) so no an necessary error message is outputted.

I'm not sure what do you want to be done in this situation, if you want the thread waits for creation of the resource if it doesn't exist, use a condition variable, and every time a resource added to array wake waiting threads up to check for the resource again.

if you don't want the thread to wait for adding resource but your problem is only that outputting "doesn't exist" error is incorrect while the resource is present at the moment that user receives error, the answer is: "there is no problem!". the resource didn't exist at the moment we checked for it, and an error reported.

update:

as you want to access multiple resource concurrently, you should lock the array for accessing that resource and then locking the resource then release lock of the array while holding the lock of the resource, but once a thread wants to delete a resource, it has to acquire lock of that resource to make sure that no other thread is using it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard synchronization problem, just control access to a std::vector containing your resources with a std::mutex (or std::shared_mutex if available and appropriate).  Nothing can grab a new resource lock until you release the overall mutex to the vector if you do it right.

Comment: I would suggest using std::list if you are managing large resources. There will be few positives, like fast adding/removing elements from the list and you will not have to reindex requests from the waiting thread because they are pointing always the correct one unless the resource will be missing.

Comment: but I would like to allow threads to access different resources in the array at the same time and not lock the whole array for each thread action

Comment: Are you able to use shared_mutex or a pthread read/write lock?  The rw lock can exclude other threads when you're updating the main vector, and then each element can have it's own lock.  When you're not adding or deleting a resource, everyone can grab a read lock, which is close to free.